# Bootstrap-select dropdown requires double tap when used with fastclick.js

Tags: bootstrap-select, fastclick.js

I am using bootstrap-select.js to stylize dropdowns. I have also used Fastclick.js.
Now, on Ipads dropdown values are changing in dopuble tap.
If I remove fastclick then dropdows works fine.
Please suggest how to use both without double tapping.

Answer (score 1):

A year late, but in case someone else stumbles upon this question:

For some reason, the *button* (and its content) of the bootstrap-select needs to be ignored by FastClick. This is done by adding the `needsclick` class to it:

```js
$("body").on("loaded.bs.select", function(e){
  // get a reference to the SelectPicker instance
  var sp = $(e.target).data("selectpicker");

  // add the `needsclick` class
  sp.$button.add(sp.$button.find("*")).addClass("needsclick");
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sbhbwwo8/)